How to properly handle shutdown in Rust
Below is a code snippet and I want to know how to gracefully handle the shutdown.
use std::{
    io::{stdin, stdout, Write},
    process::exit,
};

struct Admin {
    _i: u128,
}

impl Drop for Admin {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        // Use self to kill child processes that 
        // were spawned using tokio::process::Command::new()
        // and the child was stored in some variable in self.
    }
}

impl Admin {
    async fn work(&mut self, _msg: String) {
        // Restriction: We cannot put any condition on this loop.
        // Assume it runs infinitely, and needs mutable reference to self.
        // This is a placeholder for the admin interacting with the child processes.
        loop {
            self._i += 1;
            tokio::time::sleep(tokio::time::Duration::from_millis(500)).await;
        };
    }
}

async fn get_user_input(message: &str) -> String {
    print!("{message}");
    stdout().flush().expect("Failed to flush stdout");

    let mut input = String::new();
    match stdin().read_line(&mut input) {
        Ok(_) => input.trim().to_string(),
        Err(_) => "".to_string(),
    }
}


async fn do_work(admin: &mut Admin) {
    admin.work(get_user_input("Inp: ").await).await;
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut admin = Admin { _i: 0 };

    tokio::select! {
        _ = tokio::signal::ctrl_c() => {
            println!("Caught Ctrl + C");
        },
        _ = do_work(&mut admin) => {
            println!("Worker execution complete");
        },
    }

    println!("Dropping Admin");
    drop(admin);
    exit(0);
}


"That is because suppose the func in the loop is waiting to get user input." Okay, so implement this waiting asynchronously so you can .await it. Then the problem of when to yield goes away -- you implicitly yield any time you await async I/O. An async fn that never uses await is a design red flag.

I have updated the question and included a better, simplified code. How would you handle shutdown in this case?

It's still not clear what the problem is. Graceful shutdown will work given the updated code. Any time the main task is sleeping, it can be dropped when select! catches ^C.

Well, at this point in time, I have come to embrace the fact that there needs to be some type of waiting so that tokio can get gain control and exit. If I were to remove that sleep, then the behavior would be all over the place. Sometimes, the program just stuck and never responds to Ctrl + C and sometimes it does exit but the drop(admin) is never called.

The answer to the removal of sleep would be to put the loop in another async task or make it into smaller subroutines... Rust lifetime doesn't allow for behaviors similar to that of javascript, python, or golang, where I can just set a handler at start time, and it is triggered no matter what.

It's probably "stuck" because it's waiting on stdin. Is there a reason you're using std's stdin (which is sync) instead of tokio's (which is async)? Sync I/O is going to block the whole async task while it waits.

Removal of the sleep from the code causes the program to get stuck. Here is a method that I got to work closest to what I prefer:
use std::{
    io::{stdin, stdout, Write},
    process::exit,
    sync::{Arc, Mutex},
};
use tokio::sync::Notify;

struct Admin {
    _i: u128,
    notify: Arc<Notify>,
}

impl Drop for Admin {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        // Notify the running tasks to stop
        println!("Dropping Admin - cleaning up resources.");
        self.notify.notify_waiters();
        // Here you can handle any other necessary cleanup, e.g., terminating child processes.
    }
}

impl Admin {
    async fn work(&mut self, _msg: String) {
        let notify = self.notify.clone();
        loop {
            tokio::select! {
                _ = notify.notified() => {
                    // Exit the loop if we get notified for shutdown
                    println!("Received shutdown notification, stopping work.");
                    break;
                },
                _ = tokio::time::sleep(tokio::time::Duration::from_millis(500)) => {
                    self._i += 1;
                    println!("Working... i = {}", self._i);
                    if self._i > 5 {
                        panic!("Test...");
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }
}

async fn get_user_input(message: &str) -> String {
    print!("{message}");
    stdout().flush().expect("Failed to flush stdout");

    let mut input = String::new();
    match stdin().read_line(&mut input) {
        Ok(_) => input.trim().to_string(),
        Err(_) => "".to_string(),
    }
}

async fn do_work(admin: Arc<Mutex<Admin>>) {
    let input = tokio::spawn(async {
        get_user_input("Inp: ").await
    })
    .await
    .expect("Failed to get input");

    let mut admin_lock = admin.lock().expect("Failed to lock admin");
    admin_lock.work(input).await;
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let admin = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Admin {
        _i: 0,
        notify: Arc::new(Notify::new()),
    }));

    let admin_clone = admin.clone();

    tokio::select! {
        _ = tokio::signal::ctrl_c() => {
            println!("\nCaught Ctrl + C, initiating shutdown.");
        },
        _ = do_work(admin_clone) => {
            println!("\nWorker execution complete");
        },
    }

    println!("Dropping Admin");
    // Drop admin explicitly. This will trigger the drop method.
    drop(admin);
    exit(0);
}

No Idea if this is a good or bad way of doing things. 
This again has sleep, which actually allows the termination, but the good part is that now, I don't have to worry about "borrowed data escapes outside of function" error. Instead, I now just put an async task that can directly be called as _ = self.some_async_function() in the place of _ = tokio::time::sleep(tokio::time::Duration::from_millis(500))
